# Is HTTPs without SSL verification secure for local application?

Tags: c++, ssl, https

I am building a C++ application that needs secure connection to an SSL enabled server. I have read that for HTTPs to be fully secure, it requires the client to also use a valid certificate. But for my application, the certificate would be on disk so anyone installing the app would have access to the file. I came to the conclusion that the SSL certificate is not necessary for the application.
Am I right? Does an attacker could, somewhat, intrude into my SSL server?

Thanks a lot!

Secure HTTPs connection

Comment: Your title is confusing. HTTPS without SSL is HTTP.

Comment: You can't use HTTPs without SSL.

Comment: So you're asking if not using a SSL certificate makes your HTTPS server susceptible to attacks?

Comment: Well. Isn't Https always encrypted instead of http?
I added more precision to the question.

Comment: @Nada: Exactly :). But the server has an SSL certificate not the c++ application.

Comment: If the certificate isn't signed by an authority, most browsers will tear it as insecure. I understand that doesn't directly answer your question at all, though.

Comment: Does your server use a certificate signed by a trusted CA? If the answer is yes, you do not need to ship any certificates with your client app.

Comment: SSL connections don't have to be encrypted - there are NULL cipher suites available that do not encrypt data.  You almost have to be deliberately misconfiguring systems to use them, but they do exist.  See https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/148924/is-it-safe-to-use-tls-rsa-with-null-sha-cipher

Comment: *"I have read that for HTTPs to be fully secure, it requires the client to also use a valid certificate."* - I have no idea where you've read this (it is always recommend that you properly cite the source for such claims) but this is plain wrong. A client certificates adds no additional security to the connection itself, all what it adds is authentication of the client.

Comment: @Cen: Yes my server uses a certificate signed by a trusted CA. Thank you!

Comment: If an attacker claim to be the client and the server send it sensitive information. I think he will be able to decrypt the data?

Comment: @Cloyz: Then the server should authenticate the client. This is typically done with a username and password.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When connecting to a TLS (nowadays)-enabled server, it's the *server* certificate that is mostly relevant (although some servers request a specific certificate from the client for authentication, but that's rare since a cert isn't as easily managed as a username+password).

That means that you don't need to have a trusted certificate, since one is generated (self signed) at runtime when neeeded as part of the TLS handshake.

The same happens in some TLS-enabled services outside WWW, for example, a SMTP TLS server's certificate is practically never checked against a trusted root.

Now If you are programming a WWW server application, yes you need a trusted cert. Check [Let's Encrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/).